# unable to change dtype pandas python

Tags: string, pandas, slice

I'm working with a dataframe in `pandas` and I have a column with an `int64` data type.  I need to convert this data type to a string so that I can slice the characters, taking the first 3 chars of the 5 character column.  The code is as follows:

```
trainer_pairs[:, 'zip5'] = trainer_pairs.zip5.astype(dtype='object')
trainer_pairs.zip5.dtype
dtype('O')
```

I have confirmed the data type is an `object`, but when i try to use `str.slice()` on  the column, I still get this:

```
0      NaN
1      NaN
2      NaN
3      NaN
4      NaN
5      NaN
6      NaN
7      NaN
```

How can I successfully update the data type so that I can run this string method?

Comment: how about: `trainer_pairs['zip5'].astype(str)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you should using `astype(str)`

```
trainer_pairs['zip5'] = trainer_pairs.zip5.astype(str)
```

---

About your errors

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'zip':[1,2,3,4,5]})
df.zip.astype(object)
Out[4]: 
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
4    5
Name: zip, dtype: object
```

Even convert to object they are still `int` , doing the slice with type `int` or `float` will return the value as `NaN` . please check

```
df.zip.astype(object).apply(type)
Out[5]: 
0    <class 'int'>
1    <class 'int'>
2    <class 'int'>
3    <class 'int'>
4    <class 'int'>
Name: zip, dtype: object

df.zip.astype(str).apply(type)
Out[6]: 
0    <class 'str'>
1    <class 'str'>
2    <class 'str'>
3    <class 'str'>
4    <class 'str'>
Name: zip, dtype: object
```